# Add markers dynamically on Google Maps v2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

what are the possibilities to add markers dynamically depending on the area of the map which is shown?

I have a lot of markers or let´s say my markers need a lot of performance to be rendered, cause they are custom. I implemented it now, that only 40 markers are drawn when a "camerachange" was fired. So at this time i always render 40 new markers when cameraposition was changed.

I read about runnable and handler, are their more options? Does someone know which of these possibilities is the best, so that ui-thread isn´t blocked?

Comment: have you looked at AsyncTasks or Loaders?

Comment: @CTulip Google Maps Android API v2 must be used on the UI thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest using one of clustering libraries available for Google Maps Android API v2.

[Android Maps Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) apart from clustering can do a lot of work for you. The API is very similar to official Google library.
If you don't want to use clustering at all, you can still achieve your goal with:

```
map.setClustering(new ClusteringSettings()
    .enabled(false)
    .addMarkersDynamically(true)); // I didn't change the API to match your title ;)
```

[Clusterkraf](https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf) mainly focuses on animated clustering.

[Android Maps Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) as of this writing doesn't have clustering merged into the main branch, but you can see [clustering branch](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/clustering).

If you want to code it yourself, I can suggest these approaches:

- adding `Marker`s only in `VisibleRegion` (same thing Android Maps Extensions does when using code above), example from my demo project here: [AddOnlyVisibleMarkersExampleActivity.java](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-v2-demo/blob/master/NewMapsDemo/src/pl/mg6/newmaps/demo/AddOnlyVisibleMarkersExampleActivity.java)
- adding `Marker`s using `Handler`, example here: [AddMarkersInBackgroundExampleActivity.java](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-v2-demo/blob/master/NewMapsDemo/src/pl/mg6/newmaps/demo/AddMarkersInBackgroundExampleActivity.java)
- mix of the above; this can help a lot with app responsiveness when there are potentially hundreds of markers on screen (which you should avoid by using clustering)

Comment: I even asked you something a few days before via the issue-tracker ;) My problem is that i´m using the new android studio and need to include the library via gradle ;) I can do it manually for now, but it would be really nice if i only had to add one or two lines in a gradle-file and the dependencies are managed automatically ... it isn´t good practice to add a library directly and even check it into vcs... but for now i think i have to go with it :)

Comment: Hey Maciej, i managed to import your library into an android studio project ;) But one question, what is the best position for adding markers?

I added markers (without your library) depending on the visible area (always fetch from local database) and limit to 40 markers ... 

Should i read one time all databaseentries and let your library do the rest? Or should i now also only show visible markers?

Comment: @DieselPower I plan to add the gradle support sooner or later. As to loading, it should be best to leave the handling to the library. If you use more than few hundred, I suggest using `addMarkersDynamically` to better UX.

Comment: Just thought I'd add: 

dependencies {
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
}

Comment: If you're migraiting from Google Maps, do you have to update Marker & MarkerOptions logic as well in order to take advantage of "addMarkersDynamically" or is just specifying enough?

Comment: @AlexVPerl When using `addMarkersDynamically`, you simply add all the markers via `GoogleMap.addMarker`, but AME doesn't really add them unless it's necessary (they would be on user screen). Of course `Marker` and `MarkerOption` have to be from AME package instead of Maps Android API.

Answer (score -1):

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        latLng)
                        .title("Hello Maps ");
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            }
        });
```