# How to make a marker appear or disappear based on zoom level on Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

We all know that some of the predefined landmarks on Google Maps does not appear on a lower zoom level, but on a higher zoom level, it suddenly appears. I would like to know If I can make a customized marker not appear at lower zoom levels, then appear at higher ones.

**EDIT: Here is a snippet of my code.**

```
 // Changing marker icon
   marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.gasbig));


   // adding marker
  map.addMarker(marker);

  //position on Center

  CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
          new LatLng(14.635356, 121.03272914)).zoom(16).build();

  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

  map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
            if(arg0.zoom > 7){
                marker.visible(true);

            }


        }
    });
```

I tried the suggestion of MaciejGórski but the marker still appears on all zoom levels. I'm sorry about the question I'm still an android newbie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just added a snippet of my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that for any `Marker` you want: call `setVisible` in `OnCameraChangeListener.onCameraChange` callback with `true` or `false` depending on `CameraPosition.zoom` value.

**Edit after question edit:**

You need to keep a reference to `Marker` instead of `MarkerOptions`:

```
// adding marker
marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

and call `setVisible` on that `marker`:

```
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        marker.setVisible(cameraPosition.zoom > 7);
    }
```

Note: `setVisible` is always called there, but this might not be optimal when using many `Marker`s.

Comment: why is it "markerOptions" a parameter on marker? I thought markerOptions is a variable type.

Comment: @MiguelRivera `MarkerOptions` is a type, `markerOptions` might be a variable name.

Comment: oh okay. my apologies sir.

Comment: the logcat says I have a nullpointer exception on this line "marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.gasbig));" I have an image named as gasbig

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do it by modifying my answer to: [Android Maps v2 - animate camera to include most markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103283/android-maps-v2-animate-camera-to-include-most-markers/19104142#19104142)

Otherwise using [Android Maps Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) might be a good choice. No experince with your specific needs though.

Just realized I might have misunderstood the question. Thought you meant your own markers. Nevertheless have a look at the extensions library. Could very well be that they have something useful.

Comment: Extensions lib cannot do that (yet), but might be a good alternative when instead of hiding markers on lower zoom levels, you want them to be grouped and easily accessible on any zoom level.

Comment: Just seemed as if it can from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450081/add-markers-dynamically-on-google-maps-v2-for-android

Comment: Miguel, as I understand it, wants something like [MarkerManager in the javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markermanager).

Comment: Hi @MaciejGórski do you have some tutorial or a code that involves MarkerManager for android? I can't find one.

Comment: @MiguelRivera I don't know if such tutorial exists.