# How to plot ployline on map for more than 7000 lat long on android map

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to draw a ployline on map for more than 7000 lat long. I am getting memory issues.

Any workable solution will be help full.

Thanks,

Comment: what are you trying to draw that you need 7000 points?

Comment: I have to play location history between 2 given date time. So on an average 7000 locations are coming, and for these locations i have to draw polyline.

Comment: The user is unlikely to have a screen that is capable of showing 7000 points at once. Most likely, you will need to limit the number of points that you show to the subset that are visible, plus one "ring" of points that are outside the screen (so the lines can be drawn to them from visible points).

Comment: I agree with you, But here is the case, Location data is stored at every 30 seconds. So every 1 hour we are having 120 locations and for every 48 hours 5760 location. So we have to show the incremental polyline from where user started and where he ended / stopped between two given date time. So what is happening now is after 1500 locations are plotted using ployline on map, it slows down and some times it crashes.
Any suggestion how to over come this issue?

Comment: Answered a similar question regarding adding a lot of markers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25517475/1501613 my answer is much alike the above comments, do not expect to be able to show full tour on screen.

Comment: like everyone else is saying you wont be able to plot all that at once. What you can try to filter down the points is through checking the distance between points. If some points are really close together just throw them out since you really dont need them