# Adding more than 200 markers on google map without loading map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to add more than 200 markers on map receiving from API call
and on the movement of map i m getting another markers.
I am able to add markers but my map runs slowly.
Can anyone help me to improve map?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there are more than 200 marker then show progress indicator while loading markers in google map.

Comment: if i showing indicator that as user change map he only see indicators everywhere. it's not good

Comment: It runs slowly while you're adding the markers or it runs slowly once the markers are added ?

Comment: i am explaining you what is going on. As i got to map screen it calls API i receive 200 markers and set to map. once user change the map position i again calland again set that markers. in this procedure i get stucked

Comment: use map clustering for better experience

Comment: thanks for replay but don't want to cluster. because i m removing all previous markers.

Comment: Use an `AsyncTask` to add markers using a different thread. You can see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18451570/1411864) too. It can help you to find a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks @AllanMermod, i have puted async task for calculation and reoving and adding marker done on main thread

Comment: @AllanMermod Doesn't work